# Spring 4.1.x breaks Eclipse compilation with AspectJ and spring-aspects

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, aspectj, spring-aspects

I have a setup using Eclipse, AspectJ and Spring with compile time weaving. I've been using this for years without issues.

After upgrading from Spring 4.0.7 to 4.1.0 (or 4.1.1), there are no classes produced in the /target folder.
This problem affects only one project, that references spring-aspects.

I have other AspectJ enabled projects in my workspace, using same compiler settings and etc., but using their own aspects. Those continue to compile and output classes normally regardless of the Spring version.

The external build (Maven) works ok with both Spring 4.0 and 4.1.

I think versions are not very relevant here, but in any case I'm using AspectJ 1.8.2, Java 1.7, Eclipse Luna SR1 (also occurs on the first Luna release).

Would this be a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe if you provide a minimal [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) it would be easier for the community to reproduce the problem and answer your question.

Comment: Sounds like https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12163 to me

Comment: It might be related to that issue. But it is strange because the Maven build doesn't have the same problem. Also the workaround proposed in the issue (adding spring-context-support and jcache dependencies) doesn't help. I'll wait for the issue to be fixed and retest.

Comment: Retested after upgrading to AspectJ 1.8.3 and Spring 4.1.2 (with the fix for the issue mentioned above), and it is back to normal! Thanks for the pointer.